# Camera Bag recommendations?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which camera bag for a single DSLR camera plus 2 lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/191/which-camera-bag-for-a-single-dslr-camera-plus-2-lenses)

I am looking for a sling type camera bag that is very comfortable to carry around and is easy enough to yank my equipments out of it. I have a Canon 50D body and a couple of lens.

Comment: Seems to duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/191/which-camera-bag-for-a-single-dslr-camera-plus-2-lenses and to a lesser extent: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/non-camera-bag-suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you the reviews of the bags I have, but I can't heartily recommend any of them.  These decisions, for me, are greatly helped by also knowing what not to get and why.

I just got a [Kata 3n1-33](http://www.kata-bags.com/product.asp?Version=photo&p_Id=433) (the larger version of their bags) for traveling.  I kind of like it, in that it has all the pouches that I need and fast access to the camera.  I dislike it in that I can't carry a reflector in it.  I can also carry a laptop in it, big requirement for me.  It has a strange configuration that allows for rapid access to the camera; that's cool, but the pack weighs in excess of 20 pounds when fully loaded (with laptop, flash, camera + lens, two other prime lenses, batteries, chargers, cords, cards, dp2), so no way am I carrying this around enough to warrant the extra engineering.

Before that, I had the Lowepro Stealth Reporter (no link because I can't find it on their site, but it's the notebook+backpack version).  I liked that one because I could carry the reflector, but there were only three lens pouches, barely large enough to hold a 17-55mm f/2.8 lens (70-200 f/2.8?  Forget it) and two camera/flash pouches.  It also had a tearaway case for the laptop.  The camera had to be disassembled as well, so points to the Kata for those rare moments when I have the traveling bag and need to take the shot.

Now that I've traveled with both, I give it to the Kata, but only just.  I don't want to carry around a reflector on long trips, so giving it up is not a huge loss, but getting the straps to work every time is a pain.

On day to day trips, I have a lowepro topload zoom 2, and it's just a bit too small for a d300 and 17-55.

I hope that helps...

Comment: FWIW that link is now effectively dead.  The domain still exists and has a landing page stating that Kata has merged with Manfrotto.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Crumpler's line of messenger bags](http://www.crumpler.com/AU/Camera-Bags/Camera-Bags.html?LanguageCode=EN). The bags come with removable inserts so you can customize the bag to match your gear needs.

I personally use the 6-million dollar home, which is big enough for a couple of bodies, and a few lenses. You can select the size of bag that makes the most sense for you.

Crumpler bags are a bit pricier than some of the competition, but the price is reflected in the quality of materials and construction. Heavy duty straps, velcro, and seams, and a design that protects your gear.

Just a caveat: Messenger bags are great for walk around photography, allowing easy access to gear, but if you are planning on doing serious hiking or walking long distances, I recommend using a photo backpack instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Tamrac Adventure Zoom](http://www.tamrac.com/5513.htm) Case and attach [lens cases](http://www.tamrac.com/g_modularaccessory.htm). I love the system because it allows a lot of flexibility for taking only what I need and it leaves the camera easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Think Tank 360: http://www.rotation360.com/ - comes with both back-pack and sling bag.

Or Lowepro Slingshot: http://products.lowepro.com/product/SlingShot-200-AW,2035,4.htm