# Looking for a discreet camera bag

Tags: travel, camera-bag

I'm off next week on a bit of a world trip for 12 months. Any suggestions for a camera bag solution that meets the following (in order of importance):

1. Discreet. Must not look like it has an SLR in it ;)
2. No expensive logos (eg "krumpler" or "lowepro" etc. even though I like them)
3. Can carry bare essentials (camera body with 1 lens attached + speedlite + bottle of water + banana)
4. Will keep camera dry in rain
5. Two shoulder straps as will be carrying it every day
6. Light as possible
7. Suitable as hand luggage when flying

DIY solutions also welcome if quick and easy to do (running out of time)

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/non-camera-bag-suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a variety of padded camera bag inserts available at online stores like B&H for very little money that you can fit into a non-camera bag that you can buy elsewhere.  I found a bag at an Army Navy store that fit mine perfectly.  Photos:
http://blog.muddyboots.org/2007/08/diy-stealth-camera-bag.html

That bag is not waterproof, but I carry a garbage bag to put it in in case of rain.  I'm not sure where you could find a waterproof bag, but you can try.

Another idea is a cooler or diaper bag -they often provide a little padding and they make some nicer looking ones these days.

Answer (score 0):

The ThinkTank Retrospective are cute and might be, what you are looking for.

But I agree with Erica, it might be a better idea just to refit some old bag for this purpose.